# What's wrong with my process.php that's not causing my form to send?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have built a form which is submitted via Ajax and then processed with the mail() function in PHP. The form validation and form submission works perfectly (I can console log the data and receive a success message), yet I'm not receiving any emails from my form. I'm assuming it's the process.php.

This is my first time doing this, so also any pointers/code improvements would be much appreciated.

Javascript:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var message = $('#message').val();

var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function () {
    alert('success');
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $myemail = "name@example.com";
  $subject = "Subject";
  $message = "
  Name: $name
  E-mail: $email
  Message: $message
  ";

  mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Comment: And did you set up a mail server, how else is PHP going to send an e-mail ?

Comment: you are not retrieving the values first...using $_POST['message'] etc...

Comment: @adeneo I don't know what that is, could you please explain?

Comment: Please show all the code/form on how your using that jQuery

Comment: @Jake - To actually send emails, you have to have a webserver that has the capability of sending emails, as in having sendmail or any other email sending software set up that can send the emails. PHP does not send emails, the `mail()` function uses whatever is the default email sending software to send the email.

Comment: @adeneo Ah, that was the problem. I was running of my public Dropbox, not my server. Please post as an answer and I'll accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think indeed the problem resides within the php mail() method.
Just make sure it is, by commenting out the mail() call, and replace it with

```
echo 'I should be sending mail now!';
exit;
```

Then change your ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function (response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

Now send the form to the server, and see what comes up in the alert box.
If you get the expected string, you should indeed setup a smtp server so you can send mail.
Another option would be to use an external mailserver, but it requires you to have a proper email account somewhere else.

There are a bunch of scripts out there, check out phpmailer for instance.

Comment: The Ajax bit and the sending mail definitely is working (I'm now receiving emails), but the emails are empty. I don't think I'm referencing the data correctly.

Comment: This was a while ago but thought I'd come back and comment - You were correct and using swiftmailer solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dibs and dabs of help, I've managed to work it out.

The Ajax was all good, as expected.
The email wasn't sending because it was running locally, not using my servers mail PHP.
And the data from the form wasn't being referenced, thus returning blank emails.

SO, this is what ended up working:

```
<?php
  $myemail = "name@example.com";
  $subject = "Subject";
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $body = "
    Name: $name 
    Email: $email
    Message: $message
  ";

  mail($myemail, $subject, $body);
?>
```